# How can I display image in admin.py and one of my field in employee table is not appearing correct in admin.py?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-admin-tools, django-admin-actions

I am working on creating Employee monitoring system. I have 3 models right now. Here they are

```
class User(models.Model):
    username= models.CharField(max_length=256, verbose_name='Username')
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, verbose_name='First Name')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, verbose_name='Last Name')
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=256, verbose_name='Email')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + self.last_name

class Departments(models.Model):
    department_name= models.CharField(max_length=256, verbose_name='Departments')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.department_name


class Designation(models.Model):
    department_name= models.ForeignKey(Departments, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    designation_name=models.CharField(max_length=256, verbose_name='Designation')

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.department_name, self.designation_name)

class Employee(models.Model):
    user= models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True,)
    department_name= models.ForeignKey(Departments, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    designation_name= models.ForeignKey(Designation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    salary= models.FloatField(null=False, default=0.0, verbose_name='Salary')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'employee_images', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {} {}'.format(self.user.first_name + self.user.last_name, self.department_name.department_name, self.designation_name.designation_name)

    def image_tag(self):
        return mark_safe('<img src="/employee_images/%s" width="150" height="150" />' % (self.image))
    image_tag.short_description = 'Image'
```

my `return self.first_name +self.last_name` in `def __str__(self)` of `employee table` is not giving me any gap between these two names. I don't know how to do it.

and I have tried every method suggested by everyone on this website to display image on admin.py but I am unable to display them. Here is my admin.py

**admin.py**

```
@admin.register(Employee)
class EmployeeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display= ('first_name', 'last_name', 'designation_name', 'department', 'salary', 'image_tag')
    def first_name(self, obj):
        return obj.user.first_name
    
    def last_name(self, obj):
        return obj.user.last_name

    def designation_name(self, obj):
        return obj.designation.designation_name
    
    def department(self, obj):
        return obj.department_name.department_name
```

and one last thing my `designation_name` is not only returning me `designation_name` but also `department_name` as well. I just want `designation_name` to be appeared.

Comment: `return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future - in one `Question` on StackOverflow include only one question. Multiple issues should be divided in few topics.

When you add strings, they are connected without gap. Using `format` funtion is not usually the best way to insert variables into a `string`. You can resolve it in two ways:

```
# now
def __str__(self):
    return '{} {} {}'.format(self.user.first_name + self.user.last_name, self.department_name.department_name, self.designation_name.designation_name)

# solution 1
def __str__(self):
    return '{} {} {} {}'.format(self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name, self.department_name.department_name, self.designation_name.designation_name)

# solution 2
def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.user.first_name} {self.user.last_name} {self.department_name.department_name} {self.designation_name.designation_name}'
```

About designation_name. Look what you wrote in `__str__` method in `Designation` model.

```
class Designation(models.Model):
    ...    
    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.department_name, self.designation_name)
```

Just replace `'{} {}'.format(self.department_name, self.designation_name)` with simple `self.designation_name` and it will be fine.

And finally the admin image. According to this: https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-admin-cookbook/en/latest/imagefield.html
your `admin.py` might look similar to that:

```
@admin.register(Employee)
class EmployeeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    readonly_fields = ["show_image"]
    def show_image(self, obj):
        return mark_safe('<img src="{url}" width="{width}" height={height} />'.format(
            url=obj.image.url,
            width=obj.image.width,
            height=obj.image.height,
            )
        )

    list_display= ('first_name', 'last_name', 'designation_name', 'department', 'salary', 'image')

    def first_name(self, obj):
        return obj.user.first_name
    
    def last_name(self, obj):
        return obj.user.last_name

    def designation_name(self, obj):
        return obj.designation.designation_name
    
    def department(self, obj):
        return obj.department_name.department_name
```